# adding a service to windows from vb.net

Tags: windows, visual-studio, service

I've created a windows service application and I'm working on the installer for this service application at the moment, as there's lots of user options that need defining.

Previously when I needed to create a service I've just created a .bat file containing a relevant *SC Create* command in temp and executed it to add my service, however I wondered if there's a way to add the service directly rather than  creating and executing a bat file.

Comment: What do you mean by "directly"? What technology do you use for creating the installer?

Comment: a windows form vb app :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the temporary `.bat` file. You can run any command through [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netframework-4.7.2) without a temporary file.

Maybe you should think about your installer technology though. A VB.NET executable means people will have to run an installer for *that* first, then start it to have an installer for the service. I would be slightly amused by having to install the installer.

[Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) for example can build installer packages that install a service. Other alternatives are out there too (but this one is free).

Comment: How so? The installer app is a standalone executable... I dont understand why people would need to install that first. I agree with you that that would be a ridiculous idea :)

Comment: hm, I guess if you don't include nuget packages and don't have any settings, then it would work as a single file.

Comment: ahh yes... its a really simple forms app with nothing special at all :) 
Thanks nvoigt